# Slicing using list comprehension on a subset of a dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe, list-comprehension, slice

I want to run a list comprehension to slice names by '-' in one column in a subset defined by values in other columns.

So in this case:

```
    category   product_type   name 
0   pc         unit           hero-dominator
1   print      unit           md-ffx605
2   pc         option         keyboard1.x-963
```

I'm interested in the 'pc' category and 'unit' product type, so I want the list comprehension to only change the first row of the 'name' column to this form:

```
    category   product_type   name 
0   pc         unit           dominator
1   print      unit           md-ffx605
2   pc         option         keyboard1.x-963
```

I tried this:

```
df['name'].loc[df['product_type']=='unit'] = [x.split('-')[1] for x in df['name'].loc[df['product_type']=='unit']]
```

But I'm getting the 'list index out of range' IndexError.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `x.split('-')[1]` that expression is the likely culprit. If that expression is failing, it implies that one of the names lacks a `-` character, since `x.split('-')` would produce a list of size 1 for a name without a `-` character. A list of size 1 obviously does not have an element with an index of `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem the following way, please follow comments and feel free to ask questions:

Edit, now we consider that there could be not string elements in "name" column:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def change(row):
    if row["category"] == "pc" and row["product_type"] == "unit":
        if type(row["name"]) is str:  # check if element is string before split()
            name_split = row["name"].split("-")  # split element
            if len(name_split) == 2:  # it could be name which does not have "-" in it, check it here
                return name_split[1]  # if "-" was in name return second part of split result
            return row["name"]  # else return name without changes

    return row["name"]


# create data frame:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "category": ["pc", "print", "pc", "pc", "pc", "pc"],
        "product_type": ["unit", "unit", "option", "unit", "unit", "unit"],
        "name": ["hero-dominator", "md-ffx605", "keyboard1.x-963", np.nan, 10.24, None]
    }
)


df["name"] = df.apply(lambda row: change(row), axis=1)  # change data frame here
print(df)
```

Comment: It works great! Only it gives errors if the cell contains NaN. "'float' object has no attribute 'split'".

Comment: @currentlyunknown I added check that column "name" row value is string object. No it should work without raising exceptions. Thanks for feedback!